# Amazon AWS Permissions Per User

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to figure out a way to grant Open/Download permissions to files that users upload to a bucket of mine. I was reading this: [amazon S3 bucket policy - restricting access by referer BUT not restricting if urls are generated via query string authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886048/), and used it to implement referral based downloads, but what I'm trying to do is:
User A uploads a file, only User A and root can access said file.
User B uploads a file, only User B and root can access said file.

I'm already adding an account ID to the metadata of each file. Is it possible to use that for authentication? Run an if($s3->get_object_metadata('account_id', $file))=='123'{provide access}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. Firstly, please for the love of God, migrate to [AWS SDK for PHP 2](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/). SDK 1.x is on the way out, and hasn't received any updates in a while.
2. Having done that, you can use [S3Client::putBucketPolicy()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketPolicy) to grant access to a bucket by Canonical User ID (a.k.a., Account ID). That way, you push the responsibility of managing access control back onto the S3 service. When a user tries to access the object, they'll either get a 200 (201, 204, 304, 307), or a 403 if they're not allowed to access it.
3. If you choose to stay on SDK 1.x, the equivalent method is [AmazonS3::set_bucket_policy()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/set_bucket_policy).