# How to Give Access to non-public Amazon S3 bucket folders using Parse authenticated user

Tags: amazon-s3, parse-platform

We are developing a mobile app using Parse as our BAAS solution but using Amazon S3 for storage of our media files.  All of our users upload media files into their own individual folders inside of our app's bucket. As the user uploads media files we update their records in Parse so it knows where to download the files.  That's the easy part.

I've spent quite a bit of time researching the different policies for S3 buckets and I am trying to get a grip on the proper way to ensure the security of the content uploaded. If you do all of your work with DynamoDB or SimpleDB then it's easy because you're essentially adjusting your ACLs with the IAM accounts and whatnot.  If you use Amazon Cognito it's also easy because authentication happens through Google, Facebook or Amazon accounts.  In my case I am using Parse to authenticate users which cannot speak to Amazon directly.

My goal is that only the currently logged in Parse user with ID #1234567 can access their own 1234567 folder and files (as well as any other user given permission by this person for collaboration). Here is a post similar to what I'm trying to accomplish: [amazon S3 bucket policy - restricting access by referer BUT not restricting if urls are generated via query string authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886048/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-restricting-access-by-referer-but-not-restricting-if-u)

...but how do I accomplish this with the current user's ID number?

Even better question is whether that post mentioned above is best practice or should I instead be looking at creating an EC2 server to handle access to these files? Should I be looking at CloudFront  to serve private content? Or is there another method that works better for what I am trying to accomplish? I am going in circles and my head is spinning.

Thanks to whoever can help straighten me out.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem?

Comment: No I haven't received an answer to this question.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: Did you try asking to amazon support ?

Comment: No because I assumed that they'd tell me to just use their DynamoDB instead of Parse, and that they can't support another company's product..... But that's just my thinking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since Parse is being shut down I am migrating to another service.  This question is no longer relevant.